# Nest jQuery Inside Javascript Function To Fade In Div From Display:None

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a solution for revealing div's based on their ID, but I would like it to fade in.

Due to the complexity of the page and the fact that it is inside of WordPress I want to modify this DOM function to include a .show("slow") to make the fade in work vs. reengineering the entire page.

Here is the code:

CSS Block

```
<style>
.biobox { display:none;}
</style>
```

JavaScript That I Want To Insert jQuery Into To FadeIn
    
    var divs = ["one", "two"];
    var visibleDivId = null;

```
function toggleVisibility(divId) {
    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
    } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
    }

    hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
var i, divId, div;

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);

    if(visibleDivId === divId) {

        div.style.display = "block"; 
        //the above line I want to swap with a jquery instance that includes .show("slow"), such as this code that does not work for me $(document).ready(function(){ $(div).show("slow"); });

    } else {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

DIV's That Are Hidden By Default

```
<div class="biobox" id="one">
<img src="http://deliveringhappiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/thought-leadership1.jpg" width="346" height="346" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="biobox" id="two">
<img src="http://www.traianbadulescu.ro/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/leaders.jpg" width="402" height="317" />
</div>
```

Code To Toggle DIV Visibility Of biobox

```
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('one');">Close</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('two');">Close</a>
```

So how come `$(document).ready(function(){ $(div).show("slow"); });` doesn't work in lieu of `div.style.display = "block";`? BTW I am inserting the jQuery onto the page prior to this code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a different way of hiding your invisible `div` because you can't fade from `display: none` to another value for display, be it block, inline or inline-block.

You could transition the opacity or do something in combination with opacity, z-index or left/right offscreen hiding.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it via two classes, one with the display:none and another with opacity and using a fade in command of jQuery, but that code I found is written all in jQuery and I am not sure how to integrate it with this non-jQuery code but I'll post it tomorrow.

Thanks for confirming that you can't fade from display:none. That closes the road on a number of possible solutions.

Comment: Your jQuery for doing something like this could be as simple as a `element.toggleClass('showing');` the rest you could (or should) do in CSS.